# Sitecore TDS Webdeploy in Azure PAAS

Tags: azure, paas, tds, azure-devops

I am facing issues in Deploying TDS Webdeploy Package to Azure PAAS. I'm using Sitecore 9.3,  TDS.6.0.0.14

We are getting an error on TDS service

```
    Msg From Kudu --> "WARN  Request is redirected to document not found page. 
    Requested url: /api/TDS/WebDeploy/Status" and 
    Could not contact server at - https://AppserviceName/api/TDS/WebDeploy/Status
```

The issue is down to the last stage of the powershell script - PublishWebDeploy.ps1

Has _DEV folder in webroot which includes - web.config and TdsService.asmx
Has the below supporting dll in bin
HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.PackageInstallPostProcessor.dll
HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.Service.dll

However couldnt find the dll -- > HedgehogDevelopment.TDS.PackageInstallerService.dll for TDS TDS.6.0.0.14... Is this causing the issue ?
Or am I missing anything? Please advice !

Comment: Is this on the CD servers or CD. CD servers are very restricted in 9.1-9.3. The TDS deploy script is really only for CM. We had to modify ours to just do files since CD can accept any files nor a query of the master DB.

Comment: Sincere Apologies for late response... It was not about CD or CM.. on both servers we couldnt deploy using TDS webdeploy script... So took a workaround and fixed the issue

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple TDS projects, when you build the TDS projects, each one will generate a web deploy package (assuming you set that correctly in the project settings). You can use the `AzureRmWebAppDeployment` task (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-rm-web-app-deployment?view=azure-devops) to deploy each of the web deploy packages to the app service.

The web deploy package will handle any item updates as database scripts and update the master databases accordingly. You will need to publish those changes to the web database once deployment is complete.

Answer (score 0):

Team, For some reason the TDS webdeploy script seems to be causing issues when deploying in Azure PAAS.

As a workaround, we bundled out all the TDS Projects into one. Ie) All TDS projects will be bundled into one Webdeploy package which can be easily deployed to PAAS using standard Azure App service deploy task. This fixed my issue